# How to return file from a WCF Data Service?

Tags: wcf-data-services

Is there a way to return a file, ie a pdf or excel from a service operation method in a WCF Data Service?

For example, Lets say I have the following WCF Data Service with a single service operation. For simplicity the service operation can read the pdf from file either directly or using the ServiceProvider.

```
public class TheService : DataService<ServiceProvider>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetPdf", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
    }

        [WebGet]
        public ? GetPdf(string fileName)
        {
             byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would return the bytes of the file and the receiver should know how to handle the data (i.e. save it to a file with appropriate extension, or in a database or whatever) given the metadata information you provide with it. The data could be a simple array of bytes or you could use streaming and buffering capabilities.

Short answer is yes.

If you can provide us with further information, perhaps even some stuff that you're working on and have a particular problem with, then we could offer most specific help - as it stands this is only asking for a terse answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a separate reason for using a service operation, you could implement a Streaming Provider as outlined here: [Streaming Provider (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960144.aspx).  Then getting your file is just like accessing a property on an entity.

Comment: Well the pdf file needs to be generated from provided input parameters using a pdf library on the webservice